# Quickly get distinct values from SP list that user has permission to view

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I am pulling distinct data from a SharePoint list and attaching it to a dropdown.

At first I did it this way, and found it to be extremely slow.

```
List<Data> years = new List<Data>();
foreach (SPListItem listitem in items)
{
     SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
     if (listitem.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.Open))
     {
           string YearColumn = Convert.ToString(listitem["Year"])
           years.Add(new Data
           {
               Year = YearColumn
           });
     }
}
var distinctYear = years.GroupBy(x => x.Year, (key, group) => group.First());
```

I have since modified my code to this in hopes that it will work faster:

```
var items = listDocuments.GetItems(); 

var distinctYear = (from SPListItem i in items
                     select new
                     {
                          Year = i["Year"].ToString()                                                   
                     }).Distinct();
```

However, this returns items the user doesn't have permission to view. How can I use the GetItems method such that it only gets the items a user has permission to view? Also, is there a faster way to do this? Both of these ways seem to be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items = listDocuments.GetItems(); 
var distinctYear = (from SPListItem i in items
                 select new
                 {
                      Year = i["Year"].ToString()                                                   
                 }).Distinct();
```

This query will return only the items the user has access to view because sharepoint keeps permission levels. The reason it wasn't working before is because I had included this

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPermissions()
```

earlier in the code.